# My value is undefined in my render after I console it out and it is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, use-effect

I have two useEffects in my component. From what I understand they are executed in the order they are listed. In my second useEffect I make changes to a value created in the first and when I console out the value it is updated right before my return statement however when i got to use the value in my render it shows as undefined.. Can anyone explain why this would happen?

```
 const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const loadEntries = async (base, token) => {
      let result = await api.UserRecords.chart(userID, token);
      if (result.pageToken) {
        // another page of entries exist, load the next page
        loadEntries(base.concat(result.items), result.pageToken);
      } else {
        // received last page of entries
        let allEntries = base.concat(result.items);

        if (isPccIntegrated) {
          try {
            // for PCC integrated patients, pull any progress note from PCC and add it into the chart items
            const pccNotes = await api.PCC.progressNotes(userID);

            const notes = (pccNotes.Notes || []).map((note) => ({
              // refactor PCC notes to partially match the existing mdbox format
              isPCCNote: true,
              orgId: note.orgId,
              orgUuid: note.orgUuid,
              facId: note.facId,
              progressNoteId: note.progressNoteId,
              description: note.progressNoteType || "",
              createdAt: note.createdDate,
            }));

            // merge the mapped PCC notes into all patient notes
            allEntries = allEntries.concat(notes);

            // restort the entries by creation date, lastest first (descending order)
            allEntries.sort((a, b) => {
              if (moment(a.createdAt).isBefore(b.createdAt)) {
                return 1;
              } else if (moment(a.createdAt).isAfter(b.createdAt)) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            });
          } catch (err) {}
        }

        // loading is complete
        setEntries(allEntries);
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    };

    loadEntries([]);
  }, [isPccIntegrated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAllProviders = async () => {
      //TODO: Make conditional if entries exists
      try {
        //get all providers
        const results = await api.Providers.listnoAudit({ scope: "all" });

        const allProviders = results.items;

        //map over the entries to get providerId's out
        const providerIDs = entries.map((entry) => entry.createdBy);

        //map over response to get out provider names and id's
        const idName = allProviders.map((provider) => [provider.id, provider.fullName]);
        //find if any returned providers have matching ids to the ones in entries
        const matches = idName.filter((match) => providerIDs.includes(match[0]));
        //TODO: map over entries
        // if matches[0] = entries.createdby then
        //push matches[1] into the object at the index where match occurs
        entries.map((entry, idx) => {
          matches.map((provider) => {
            if (entry.createdBy === provider[0]) {
              let en = { ...entry, fullName: provider[1] };
              entries.splice(idx, 1, en);
            }
          });
          return entries;
        });
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    loadAllProviders();
  }, [entries]);

...

  
//this one returns the entries with the fullName value
  console.log(entries)
  return (
    {entries.map((entry, idx) => (
    <p>{entry.fullName}</p>
    )
    )
```

Comment: can you create a minimal code? That is just too big code sample

Comment: I was able to remove alot of the render statement logic. But I feel like you might need to see the logic outside the render? Specifially how `entries` is set and updated

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the state directly. In the 2nd `useEffect` hook, you are mutating the `entries` state which is not how you should update the state. Also note that you do not save the array returned by the `map` methods, so the result of `map` method is discarded. `map()` might not be the right method to use in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean about mutating my state. I am new to developing so .map is my go to when handling data. But I am wondering what a better method would be. I was looking into `.reduce` but this seems like not a good use case for it. Any tips?

Comment: I could make a copy of `entries` and splice the values there to create a new state of `entriesWithNames` ? But could you explain what you mean by discarding the result of my map?

Comment: `map` method is used to transform the values inside an array and it returns a new array with the transformed values. You don't save the return value of `map` method in any variable and that is what i meant by _result of map method getting discarded_. If you want to iterate over an array and do some operation, `forEach` method is the right method to use.